# Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' method. None of the following functions is suitable:

Tags: android

I had a problem in android studio by part of my codes underlined red.
Can you help me?
there is my code below.

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 |
| cell 3 | cell 4 |

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 |
| cell 3 | cell 4 |

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 |
| cell 3 | cell 4 |

```
)
BottomAppBar {
    items.forEach {
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = (
                    Icon(painter = painterResource(id = it.icon), contentDescription = it.title)
                    ),
            selected = selectedRoute
        ) {
            navController.navigate(it.route) {
                navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { route ->
                    selectedRoute = it.route
                    popUpTo(route) {
                        saveState = true
                    }
                }
                launchSingleTop = true
                restore State = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```